# WorkingThread not started

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a C# understanding problem.
The following code:

```
this.workingThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(this.WorkingThreadFunction));
```

is definitely called, but somehow I don't come in that function:

```
private void WorkingThreadFunction(object args) {}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call [Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/a9fyxz7d(v=vs.110).aspx) on your thread for it to actually start.

```
this.workingThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(this.WorkingThreadFunction));
this.workingThread.Start();
```

Comment: Oh my god, I'm so sorry.